# How to update a associative array column with REST API?

Tags: php, rest, curl, parse-platform, put

I am in a pinch. I need to update (PUT) a row with an associative array column in Parse.com . but I cannot figure out how to do this and I couldn't find anything in the documentation at parse.com . I am programming in PHP and I created my own cURL wrapper (In other words i need someone to tell me how the URL needs to look like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is listed in the docs here: https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-updating

```
curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: app-id-here" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: rest-api-key-here" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":73453}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/class-name-here/object-id-here
```

where the data is a json encoded object of the updated keys.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I meant a associative array with a key-value pair. I updated my question.

Comment: associative arrays are encoded as objects in json, so, {'score':{'level1':10,'level2':5}}

Comment: Hey Fosco, I appreciate your help but still have a question. It seems my previous information inside the array gets removed. The array looks like this `"campaign":{{"dateAdded":"2014-04-30","id":"TQxDUMWYKI"},{"dateAdded":"2014-04-30","id":"KFxDUMWYKI"}}` . I only want to update the date in my first sub-array. Do I have to GET  the entire array first in order to update the whole array without losing my previous information.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to get the whole object value and update it.  Array column types (non-associative) can use the add/remove/addUnique methods to update without replacing the whole column data.